# How to add selected items on a page to a separate block in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, jquery, knockoutjs, knockout

Please help with the implementation of this functionality. I have a separate module with a separate route.

There will be elements on the page (picture and checkbox under it) as in the screenshot.

[image]

And when you click the checkbox, the picture should be added to another block below.

I have a module and a file that shows the elements on the page.

> app/code/Test/Module/view/frontend/templates/items.phtml

This is the markup of these elements.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h4>elements set</h4>
    <div class="elements-wrapper">
        <div class="element-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Test_Module::images/image1.png'); ?>" />
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sample-item-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Test_Module::images/image1.png'); ?>" />
            <div class="pretty p-default">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help with the implementation of the functionality that will add the selected item to a separate block

Comment: can you share more details with code?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel I have only this code + layout which renders the + route block + module initialization file. I can’t come up with the implementation of this functionality, so I turned to the community

Comment: ok, so you need using jquery I can do that.

Comment: Because In your image there are multiple Items and In code, It Seems only one.

Comment: are you understand what I am saying?

Comment: there is no click event method and no block file where you want to display.

Comment: So, tell me so I can write code for you.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel two element set blocks were shown as an example, so that values ​​could be obtained not only from one block, for example, if there is a page constructor that can duplicate elements set. The block to which you need to add selected elements can be a simple div, it is not so important as the interactive functionality itself

Comment: ok, so I can share one URL to check where I can make a filter module. let it check and then let me know you need like that.

Comment: please see here I just create a filter module where users select filtration and selected div display on right side.  https://magento-331546-1017597.cloudwaysapps.com/magefilter/index/products/

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel I do not understand why this example with filters. all I need to track the status of the checkboxes on the page, if the checkbox is active, then the picture to which this checkbox belongs should be added to a separate block below

Comment: ok please find out my E - mail from my profile I will explain to you. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102785/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-ann-karsksya).

Comment: ok sure as well I sent the message in the room please come